# Regular Expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I don't know how to find the string using regular expression, the format of string is below.

[ any symbol 0~n times any number 1~n times] 1~n times.

It's seems like phone number matched. But the difference is that can insert any symbols and white space between numbers, for example

```
458###666###2##111####111
OR
(123)))444###555%%6222%%%%
```

I don't know if I explain the question clearly.
Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: I did not understand the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this represents the pattern you described

```
^(?:(\D?)\1*\d+)+$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u5hp)

`^` matches the start of the string

`(\D?)\1*` will match an optional non digit (`\D`), put it into a backreference and match this same character again 0 or more times using `\1*`

`\d+` at least 1 digit

`(?:(\D?)\1*\d+)+` the complete non capturing group is repeated 1 or more times

`$` matches the end of the string

It will match

> 458###666###2##111####111
>   (123)))444###555%%6222%%%%1
>   (((((((((123)))444###555%%6222%%%%1

But not

> s(123)))444###555%%6222%%%%1
>   (123)))444###555%%6222%%%%

Your statement:

> [ any symbol 0~n times any number 1~n times] 1~n times.

does not fit to your second example `(123)))444###555%%6222%%%%` that does not end with a digit.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to gather all the groups of digits from the string you can use `\d+` regex:

```
>>> re.findall('\d+', '458###666###2##111####111 OR (123)))444###555%%6222%%%%')
['458', '666', '2', '111', '111', '123', '444', '555', '6222']
```

Answer (score 0):

[ NOTE, I am ignoring the 'in python', opting instead for a more general 'build regular expressions' answer, in the hope that this will not only provide the desired answer but be something to take away for different RE-related problems ]

First, you want to match any symbol (or possibly any symbol, except a number), 0 or more times. That would be one of `.*` or `[^0-9]*` (the first is the 'anything wildcard', the second is a character class of everything except the numbers 0 to 9. The `*` is a 'match at least no times'.

Second, you want to match one or more digits. That, too, is relatively easy: `[0-9]+` (or if you have a sufficiently old and anal RE library, `[0-9][0-9]*`, but that is highly unlikely to be the case outside a CS exam).

Third, you want to group that and repeat the grouping at least one time.

The general syntax for grouping is to enclose the group in parentheses (except in emacs, where you need \(, as the plain parenthesis is frequently matched). So, something along the lines of `([^0-9]*[0-9]+)+` should do the trick.